# Reputation graph goes to 2020

Tags: feature-request, bug, reputation-graph

From [my profile](https://superuser.com/users/301042/ooker):

[image]

It's the same with months:

[image]

Happy new year.

Comment: Stack Exchange® Time Machine™

Comment: is that a meme or just something you just come up?

Comment: Indeed, but [another meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316142/350567) actually.

Comment: Also reported on Stack Overflow : [Reputation graph x-axis labels seem off-by-one on profile activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378872/reputation-graph-x-axis-labels-seem-off-by-one-on-profile-activity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, actually.

After closer inspection, looks like the actual reputation value for the written date is to the right of the text. Without vertical graph lines, it's hard to notice, but it's pretty clear in the graph of [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/441695/u9-forward?tab=topactivity):

> [image]

As can be seen in their reputation tab, they had 275 rep in December 23 (2018), where the vertical red line I added is located. Based on that same logic, the actual rep for the last date is the end of the graph.

So nothing really "goes into 2019", the graph ends in 2019, and since in your case it spans several years, it can't go into actual dates as in the above, where the user is member for less than a month.

Comment: so it's not a bug, but is still something the team has to fix I think. Minor questions: (1) how do you find that users? (2) When you say "that user" I think you're referring at me.

Comment: @Ooker so feel free to start a feature request and specify how exactly you want to see the graph instead. To be honest, I doubt it will be popular, but you can try. Answers: 1) I didn't really search, just randomly looked in few profiles of users posting in front page. 2) No, "that user" is linked to the user having the graph I posted, not you.

Comment: This is then still surely a bug - the axis labels are in the incorrect position